# Reference books for highschool Algebra and Geometry?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I'm tutoring high school students in Math for a local College and Career prep program and would like to have a reference book on hand that I can consult.  I'm a Comp Sci graduate so I have a pretty strong background in Math but it's been a while since I used high school level Algebra and Geometry.

Are there any good reference books that I could have on hand to brush up if I run into something I don't remember?  I typically just need to browse a short description and an example before things start coming back and I can help students.  Preferably cheap, I probably won't need it very often after a few months of tutoring.  The ideal book would be something that is quickly browsable with a concise description of topics, and maybe cross references to related topics.

Comment: Search free ebooks at project Gutenberg (http://www.gutenberg.org/) and you will find samples of both and the price is right! You might also want to get Schaum's outline in both subjects and might find them for a penny in both Algebra and Geometry! HTH ~A

Comment: I run a site called theassyer.org that catalogs free books. My general experience is that free books in math are heavily weighted toward the higher levels, e.g., graduate-level texts. It gets to be slim pickings when you get to the K-12 level. I don't see anything reasonable for high school geometry.

Comment: @BenCrowell After looking through project Gutenberg that seems to be the case there too.