# Pre-College Maths Textbooks

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, reference-request, trigonometry

I am a high school student searching for some mathematics books covering material all the way up to, but not including, college level mathematics. I have already read Gelfand's books and Lang's Basic Mathematics, and enjoyed them thoroughly. Yet I do not feel I have thoroughly mastered all facets of high school maths, and would like to do so before moving on. Are there any other books that it could be beneficial for me to study at this stage?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81579/books-for-high-school-students-starting-on-college-math?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137556/best-self-study-math-books?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601742/obtaining-a-deeper-understanding-of-lower-level-mathematics?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199372/reference-books-for-highschool-algebra-and-geometry?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10543/books-that-develop-interest-critical-thinking-among-high-school-students?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183617/looking-to-attain-fluency-in-mathematics-not-academic-mastery?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571356/i-almost-quit-self-studying-mathematics-but-should-i-continue?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98092/i-want-to-study-mathematics-ahead-of-high-school-but-i-found-that-im-rusty-on?rq=1

Comment: Amzoti's references are quite good. Moreover, you need to be specific to what you want. You are the only one that knows your strength/weaknesses or where you want your mathematical journey to take you. You would get better answers if you asked for example, 'what are books to get better at plane geometry' then asking for 'books that will get me better at Math'.

Comment: There is no inherent difference between high school and college mathematics. As @mathematics2x2life says, you should focus on the sort of math you want to learn, rather than worrying about what sort of building it tends to be taught in.

Comment: My only substantive suggestion: if you don't understand "algebra 2" or "intermediate algebra" or "precalculus" (whatever it may be called in your school), I suggest you try not to worry about it: a lot of that stuff is often taught in entirely the wrong order and won't make sense until you've learned some other things.

Answer (score 2):

[Spivak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098918),[Engel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191),[Polya](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069111966X),[Andrews](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=number%20theory%20andrews&sprefix=number+theory+and%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Anumber%20theory%20andrews&ajr=2),[Courant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195105192). All amazing, and help you get a grasp of what math is (not that I know myself).

These books are not necessarily part of the high school curriculum, but I believe they really hel develop your mathematical maturity, which really smoothens the learning process.